# lock_guard two critical sections with one mutex

Tags: multithreading, c++11, dictionary, thread-safety, locking

I have `Get()` and `Set()` methods and I want to make them thread safe. Wondering if I should use two mutex, one for Get and second one for Set or can I use one mutex, as in the code below.

```
public:
float Get(string name){
  lock_guard<mutex> lock(mutex1);
  return value_map[name];
}

Set(string name, float value){
  lock_guard<mutex> lock(mutex1);
  value_map[name] = value;
}

private:
map<string, float> value_map;
mutex mutex1;
```

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You must use the same mutex for both. Two mutexes would be just as useless as no mutex at all - you'd still have a data race between `Get` and `Set`.